# Node.js: Reading long JSON file always cuts last closing bracket character

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, utf-8, base64

I have a the following:

```
let base64strings = ["U2FsdGVkX1+lWCC8X04S/duu480r0BkPvea...", ....]

let writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.json')
let index = 0

for (const base64string of base64strings) {
  writableStream.cork()

  let textForStream = ''

  if (index === 0) {
    textForStream += '['
  } else {
    textForStream += ','
  }

  textForStream += JSON.stringify({ index, data: base64string })

  if (index === (base64strings.length - 1)) {
    textForStream += ']'
  }

  writableStream.write(textForStream)

  writableStream.uncork()

  index++
}

let check = fs.readFileSync('test.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' })

let arr = JSON.parse(check) // <--- this breaks with a *SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input*
```

That is because the last character of `check` which is supposed to be a `]` is now missing. It gets cut off every time when I read the file, even though it's there in the test.json when I open it up.

However, if I then open up test.json in my editor everything looks fine:

```
[{"index":0,"data":"U2FsdGVkX1+lWCC8X04S/duu480r0BkPvea..."},{"index":1,"data":"U2FsdGVkX1+lWCC8X04S/duu480r0BkPvea..."}, ...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I *guess* it's the `{ encoding: 'utf-8' }` that messes things up but I don't  how to fix this.

Comment: Why not create the write stream with the encoding as well?

Comment: Why is this not needed in the 1st, working, scenario? I will try it though.

Comment: You may also want to read Node's [advice on Buffering](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering), which is likely where your problem is occurring. You need to wait for the buffer to be written to the filesystem before reading. That page is chock full of information about the streaming API.

Comment: I make multiple 'write.()' s actually inside a loop, but I omitted that for readability. I will update the OP. I guess I need to wait for "drain" at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `cork()` and `uncork()` calls and I'm now waiting for `drain` after each loop and it works:

```
function forDrain(stream) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    stream.once('drain', resolve)
  })
}

let base64strings = ["U2FsdGVkX1+lWCC8X04S/duu480r0BkPvea...", ....]

let writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('test.json')
let index = 0

for (const base64string of base64strings) {   
  let textForStream = ''

  if (index === 0) {
    textForStream += '['
  } else {
    textForStream += ','
  }

  textForStream += JSON.stringify({ index, data: base64string })

  if (index === (base64strings.length - 1)) {
    textForStream += ']'
  }

  writableStream.write(textForStream)

  await forDrain(writableStream)
    
  index++
}

writableStream.end()

let check = fs.readFileSync('test.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' })

console.log(JSON.parse(check).join('') === base64strings.join('')) // true
```